# .Net Core - Application Crashing while debugging

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

Something really strange is happening. If i place a break point after a certain line of code, when debugging, the debug session stops as if i hit the "Stop" button.
What's really strange is that, if i skip that function altogether, jumping over it, the code does not crash...

I'm using .Net Core 2, <strike>running in a fully updated VS For Mac</strike> on any VS (windows and Mac), using C# 7.1

heres the code:

```
        var connectionToUse = new SqlConnection(string.Format(str, dbName));
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connectionToUse;
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT * from myTable";
            await connectionToUse.OpenAsync(); //CANT GET PAST THIS LINE HERE
            var r1 = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            while (await r1.ReadAsync())
            {
                //MORE CODE
            }
            r1.Close();
            await Task.Delay(15000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //NEVER ENTERS HERE
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connectionToUse.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connectionToUse.Close();
            }
        }
```

**Edit1:**
Using `.Open()`, no async, works perfectly. But the problem moves to the `r1.ReadAsync()` line...

**Edit2:**
prior to that code, the following one runs perfectly

```
    private async Task<Dictionary<int, string>> MapDatabases()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> databases = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        SqlConnection mainConn = new SqlConnection(string.Format(str, "Master"));
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT name,database_id FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = 5";
        command.Connection = mainConn;
        try
        {
            await mainConn.OpenAsync();
            SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                databases.Add(reader.GetInt32(1), reader.GetString(0));
            }
            reader.Close();
            mainConn.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mainConn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                mainConn.Close();
            }
        }
        return databases;
    }
```

**EDIT3:**
Also reproducible on VS 2017 fully updated.

**EDIT4:**
Apparently theres something wrong with the `await` statement. I found out that the code will crash in the first subsequent `await`, no matter where it is

Comment: Does the database exist? When you debug the code, is it using the same connection string (from the relevant appsettings.json file) as when you run it without debugging?

Comment: @JamieTaylor Yes, the database exists and the code works as expected if i don't use the async versions

Comment: Maybe a debugger bug. I would report it on the [Visual Studio for Mac developer forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/41/index.html) and attach the IDE log and the debugger output. Also a small repro project, if possible, would be useful too.

Comment: @MattWard damn, this happens on VS 2017 for windows also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda figured out... I was spanning new threads using `Task.StartNew`. After changing to `Task.Run` things started working properly. Can't figure out why the debug session was crashing though... Since the code is working as expected, i'm accepting this as answer.

Comment: `StartNew` uses the `Current` synchronization context, so your work (probably) eventually get run on UI thread, more on this here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html